# Why does the graph have tick and thin lines?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have the following code:

```
RdmMatrix = vertcat(Round_deviation_mean {:});
rslMatrix = vertcat(roundsumlive {:});
correctsMatrix=vertcat(corrects{:});
A = [ RdmMatrix(:,1), rslMatrix(:,1) ];

figure(88);
bar([RdmMatrix(:,1) rslMatrix(:,1)], 0.05, 'stack');
legend('Correct', 'Functioning');
xlabel('Run');
ylabel('Sensor Count');
hold on;
```

I am not sure I understand the following outout can anyone help?!

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPoPj.jpg)

```
the data of round deviation mean are zeros

here are data from 65 to 100 of round sumlive
```

23.000 19.000 17.000 16.000 38.000 35.000 31.000 25.000 23.000 19.000 16.000 14.000
13.000 11.000 36.000 33.000 31.000 28.000 25.000 21.000 20.000 20.000 14.000 12.000
38.000 35.000 31.000 26.000 23.000 16.000 15.000 13.000 12.000 10.000 37.000

Comment: If you round the data first, does it get better?

Comment: round does not mean rounding i mean n rounds i.e. n measurements

Comment: I mean round as in rounding. Maybe there are some rounding errors that lead to double-bars? Alternatively, if there are no double bars, it's a simple graphics problem that you may be able to fix by zooming/resizing the figure.

Comment: sumlive are integers and deviation here are all zeros @Jonas

Comment: If you zoom in on one of the thick bars, does it show up as double bar, or are all the bars the same width if you zoom such that you see one thin and one thick bar only?

Comment: when I zoom in it shows as single bar and all bars are of the same width. after several zooms @Jonas

Comment: is there a way to fix it or i should zoom @Jonas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best choice was to decrease the number of runs by taking the mean.